# .NET Bundler - JS and CSS bundles not being referenced once hosted

Tags: .net, bundle, internet-explorer-11

I have created a css bundle and a javascript bundle using BundleConfig.cs...

```
        //JQWidgets js
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/JQWidgetsBundle").Include(
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxcombobox.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.edit.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.aggregates.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.grouping.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.pager.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.filter.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxscrollview.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxwindow.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxtabs.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxinput.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxradiobutton.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxdatetimeinput.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxcalendar.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxtooltip.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.export.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxdata.export.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxdragdrop.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxnotification.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxvalidator.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxmaskedinput.js",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/jqxexpander.js"));

        //Site and widget css
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
          "~/content/site.css",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.shinyblack.css",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.fresh.css",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.metrodark.css",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.custom-blue.css",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.ui-darkness.css",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.blueinput.css",
          "~/content/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.shinyYellow.css"));
```

And then rendering them in my master page:

```
 <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/JQWidgetsBundle") %>
 <%: Styles.Render("~/bundles/css") %>
```

They work great locally. However, once I publish, there is a problem.

Using the IE 11 Dev tools, I can see the two bundles rendering in the markup:

```html
<link href="/WorkBench/bundles/css?v=Q6kSp5-_my19zcs0pa9EpK9CaoiSCvZ0gnO5isqNSUs1" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/WorkBench/bundles/JQWidgetsBundle?v=u7yU5h32xArwAIPVl6NesT5AzeHxNSUjKmxunXkySUw1"></script>
```

However, they aren't actually getting opened by the browser...

[image]

My site is not showing any styling from the css bundle, and has no functionality from the js bundle.

What am I missing? Is there some kind of trick to getting these bundles to open? Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what does your `BundleConfig.cs` look like?  Also, are you actually publishing the `.js` and '.css` files (i.e. have you confirmed that they are published to the server)?

Comment: I've added the BundleConfig.cs code to the post. Yes, all the resources are indeed getting published, as the site works perfectly when I remove the bundling and reference each resource individually.

Answer (score 1):

May be this link will help [jQWidgets ASP.NET MVC5](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/aspnetmvc/index.htm) - there are screenshots and code for creating jQWidgets Bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the compilation is set to debug false in the web config.

Also, you can try,

> BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true

to enforce the bundling in code level.